# Ubuntu running very slow after install (16.04.3)

Tags: boot

After having a hard time installing Ubuntu on my PC (did not boot to UEFI correctly, had to use legacy, didn't recognize Windows, so I made a new partition for it instead of dual booting), it's running extremely slow. I'd say around 5 FPS. However, when I was trying it before installing, it ran perfectly fine. So, I'd really like to know the cause of this. Keep in mind I do not dual boot to Ubuntu, I just boot straight to my hard drive instead of Windows Boot Manager.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, this could be about a lot of things, but the main thing you're talking about is that everything's fine when running from USB, but not from hard drive. Is it possible that the HDD is failing? Did/does any other operating system working fine from the HDD? Or is it all slow?

I might as well throw in: did you do a clean install?

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. But you don't have enough rep points to post a comment. There have been lots of posts about Ubuntu 16.04 running slow so I think there is more than a simple solution to this problem.

Comment: I understand. Apologies.

Comment: The HDD is perfectly fine and Windows technically exists on the HDD, however, it is UEFI and not Legacy. Windows runs perfectly fine too. So, if I could think of what it is, it's probably that since my computer is set to run on UEFI, it does not work well with Legacy booting. Keep in mind I figured out that is was just my GPU preventing me from booting to UEFI since I heard a sound that you get when you click at the wrong place when I booted to UEFI. Also, keep in mind that is was just garbage on the screen that I got when I booted to UEFI, even though I have a GTX 970 and it should work fine.

Comment: And what's a clean install?